# Appell in einem Kurs oder einer Klasse

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Wenn in meinem Heimatland der Leiter in die Klasse (besonders in der Schule) eintritt, ist es üblich, zu prüfen, ob alle Schüler/innen anwesend sind.
Ist das auch in Deutschland üblich? Ich habe gelernt, dass das »Appell« heißt. Ist das richtig?

Comment: Du meinst *der **Lehrer** in die Klasse kommt*, oder?

Comment: In der DDR war es üblich, dass ein Schüler zum Beginn der Stunde meldete, dass die Klasse zum Unterricht bereit sei und ggf. wer fehlt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ich kann nicht für Deutschland sprechen, weil ich nicht dort lebe, sondern für Österreich. Aber ich habe die starke Vermutung, dass es in Deutschland auch so ist wie hier geschildert:

Das Wort *»Appell«* hat zwar auch die Bedeutung einer Anwesenheitsüberprüfung, aber das ist eine Nebenbedeutung, und die ist nur beim Militär üblich.

**Appell beim Militär**
Beim Bundesheer (bzw. in Deutschland bei der Bundeswehr) gibt es den Morgenappell: Die Rekruten werden um 6 Uhr morgens geweckt und haben dann 1 Stunde Zeit für Körperpflege und Frühstück. Um 7 Uhr müssen sie sich dann am Kasernenhof in Reih und Glied aufstellen. Anschließend verließt der Kommandant der Reihe nach die Namen der einzelnen Soldaten. Jeder Soldat, der seinen Namen hört, meldet sich daraufhin mit einem lauten *»Hier«.* Auf diese Weise wird überprüft, ob alle Soldaten zum Dienst angetreten sind.

**Anwesenheitskontrolle in Schulen**
In Schulen gibt es auch eine Anwesenheitskontrolle, aber die wird nicht *»Appell«* sondern *»Anwesenheitskontrolle«* genannt und läuft meist weit weniger formell ab. In den meisten Fällen kennt die Lehrerin bzw. der Lehrer die eigene Klasse so gut, dass das Fehlen einzelner Schüler sofort auffällt, wenn die Lehrperson nach dem Betreten des Klassenzimmers den Blick über die anwesenden Schüler streifen lässt. Oft fragt die Lehrperson auch, ob jemand fehlt, denn die Schüler bemerken ja auch die Abwesenheit ihrer Schulkollegen.

**Anwesenheitskontrolle in Hochschulen**
Ich unterrichte an einer Hochschule, da habe ich es nicht mit Schülern zu tun, sondern mit Studenten.<sup>1</sup> Weil hier die Lehrbeauftragten eine größere Anzahl an Studierenden betreuen, kennen die Lehrbeauftragten die Studierenden nicht gut genug, um nur durch Augenschein zu erkennen wer fehlt.

Daher gibt es Anwesenheitslisten. Die/der Lehrbeauftragte druckt vor Beginn des Unterrichts eine Namensliste der Studierenden aus und gibt diesen Zettel am Beginn des Unterricht den Studierenden. Diese bestätigen durch ihre Unterschrift ihre Anwesenheit und geben den Zettel an den Nachbarn bzw. die Nachbarin weiter. Das passiert während des Unterrichts. Wenn alle unterschrieben haben, trägt eine(r) der Studierenden den Zettel wieder zum/zur Lehrbeauftragten.

---

**Hauptbedeutung des Wortes *»Appell«***
Das Wort *»Appell«* wird meist in einer ganz anderen Bedeutung verwendet, nämlich in der Bedeutung *»dringliche Aufforderung«:* Wenn man jemanden sehr eindringlich auffordert, etwas bestimmtes zu tun, nennt man das einen Appell.

Ein Beispiel für einen Appell ist die Aufforderung der Regierung an die Bevölkerung, während einer Pandemie Abstand zu anderen Menschen zu halten.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Ein Schüler ist eine lernende Person, die noch nicht die Hochschulreife erreicht hat. (Die Hochschulreife heißt in Deutschland *»Abitur«,* in allen anderen deutschsprachigen Ländern *»Matura«.*) Diese Personen sind meist Kinder und Jugendliche, die jünger als ca. 18 Jahre sind. Lernende Personen, die berechtigt sind eine Universität oder Fachhochschule zu besuchen, heißen *»Studenten«.* Studenten sind erwachsene Menschen, also älter als 18 Jahre.</sub>

Comment: Diese Antwort ist soooo perfekt. Vielen Dank für ihre Hilfe

Comment: Ja, ziemlich perfekt. Aber auch auf deutsch gibt es den Begriff "Morgenappell" in der Schule, auch wenn es das Ding an sich in deutschsprachigen Schulen i.A. nicht (mehr) gibt. Wenn wir also beschreiben würden, was in einem anderen Land passiert, würden wir es wie in der Frage richtig angenommen, "[Morgen]appell" nennen.

Comment: Ich würde gern anmerken, dass es (zumindest in Deutschland) auch andere Formen der Anwesenheitsprüfung an Hochschulen gibt (insbesondere das namentliche Aufrufen vor Prüfungen), die aber alle nicht als "Appell" bezeichnet werden.

Comment: Mit Konstrukten wie [G8](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abitur_nach_der_zw%C3%B6lften_Jahrgangsstufe) sind auch Studierende unter 18 öfter an den Unis/FHs. Minderjährige haben (wenigstens in NRW) sogar einen Vorrang bei NC-Zulassungen. [§ 26 Abs. 1.4](https://recht.nrw.de/lmi/owa/br_vbl_detail_text?anw_nr=6&vd_id=18909&ver=8&val=18909&sg=0&menu=1&vd_back=N)

Comment: in Österreich wird an Hochschulen die Anwesenheitspflicht kontrolliert? In meinem ganzen Studium in DE hatte ich keine einzige Veranstaltung, in der das jemals überprüft wurde.

Comment: @Polygnome: Hier gibt es (zumindest in Ö) einen Unterschied zwischen Universitäten und Fachhochschulen. Als ich an einer Uni studiert habe (1980er-Jahre), gab es auch keine Anwesenheitspflicht. Ich habe später (2006-2009) nochmal an einer FH in Wien studiert (»FH Technikum Wien«), da musste man zu 80% der Präsenzzeit anwesend sein. An der »FH St. Pölten«, an der ich jetzt unterrichte gibt es in den Studiengängen des Department Informatik und Security eine Anwesenheitspflicht von 50%. Wie die Anwesenheitspflicht in den anderen fünf Departments oder an anderen FHs geregelt ist, weiß ich nicht.

Comment: ... Diese Anwesenheitspflicht ist nicht gesetzlich vorgeschrieben. Im Fachhochschulgesetz sind lediglich Ausnahmen davon für Studierendenvertreter geregelt, im Universitätsgesetz sind nicht mal Ausnahmen erwähnt. (Zwei andere Unterschiede zwischen FHs und Unis: Studierende an FHs müssen einen Studienbeitrag zahlen, Studierende an Unis jedoch nicht. FHs haben einen expliziten Praxisbezug (»angewandte Wissenschaften«), Unis nicht.)

Comment: @Polygnome: Während meiner nicht allzu lang zurückliegenden Zeit, in der ich an einer Universität in Deutschland im Bereich Informatik auch an Lehrveranstaltungen mitgewirkt habe, gab es durchaus Veranstaltungen mit Anwesenheitskontrolle. Das waren in der Tat nicht die Vorlesungen selber, aber neben den bereits genannten Prüfungen (bei denen einfach kontrolliert wird, wer von den Angemeldeten die Prüfung auch tatsächlich antritt) auch einzelne Übungsstunden, bei denen die (90-prozentige oder so) Anwesenheit eine Voraussetzung war, um den "Schein" für die Veranstaltung zu erhalten.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Bei Prüfungen ist es irgendwie selbstverständlich, dass da die Personalien kontrolliert werden. genauso wenn es Testate zum erlangen des Scheines gibt. Für Übungen habe ich *nie* Anwesenheitspflicht erlebt -- man musste zwar die Übungen bearbeiten und eine gewisse Punktezahl erreichen (i.d.R. 50%), aber Anwesenheitspflicht gabs da nie (außer halt für Testate).

Answer (score 3):

Das kommt ganz auf die Schule an. Im Normalfall wird jedoch nur in der ersten Stunde die Anwesenheit kontrolliert, um unentschuldigtem Fehlen nachzugehen. Das ist nötig, da die Schulen (bzw. der Lehrer) die Aufsichtspflicht hat, und sicherstellen muss, dass keinem Schüler etwas passiert (zum Beispiel auf dem Schulweg). Desweiteren besteht natürlich Schulpflicht, die eingehalten werden muss, und daher unentschuldigtem Fehlen nachgegangen werden muss.

Gut möglich, dass vor allem früher hierfür "Appell" verwendet wurde, heutzutage sagt man dazu im Normallfall schlicht "Anwesenheitskontrolle".